# iOS- Obj-c - How can I Load cell from NSMutableArray in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to load datas from NSMutableArray to my TableView Sections
in my app i download datas from JSON database and sections Count and cells count are in that jSON file so the variables are not stable!
i want to load a NSMutableArray ObjectAtIndex in to cell (in the section) (i should to check if the Object should be in section 1 or in section 2 !)
Here is part of my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProjectCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (int i = 0; i<[ProjectsToLoad count]; i++) {
        Project *loader = [ProjectsToLoad objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([loader group_id] == ([indexPath section]+1))
        {
            [cell.textLabel setText:[loader title]];
            NSLog(@"LOADED CELL IS : %@ , %i" , [loader title] , [indexPath section]);
        }
    }
return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE : how can i return an array of cells Instead of returning a cell?**

Comment: There is no such word as "datas".

Comment: UPDATE : how can i return an array of cells Instead of returning a cell?

Comment: What is the issue ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee i cannot see all name of projects (all of the cells have the same Title !)

Comment: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called once for each cell, that is the way it works. `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `numberOfSections:` provide the basis for the calls to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @Zaph that means i should run 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' function for each cell ?

Comment: try using the array like this : Project *loader = [ProjectsToLoad objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: You dont need a loop on the array .. just get the element out depending on the indexPath of the cell.. so you loop on the array based on the cell.

Comment: You do not call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it is called as cells are needed for display and you provide the cell for the section and row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you want to achieve. You cannot fill "datas" in `UITableView`. `UITableViewController` to fill `UITableView` uses special functions defined as `UITableViewDataSource`. If you want to have all data from your `ProjectToLoad` in one section you should:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [ProjectsToLoad count];
}
```

And then your cellAtRow will looks like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProjectCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Project *loader = [ProjectsToLoad objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[loader title]];;
    return cell;
}
```

If source is changing, you should refresh data using one of these function:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:];
[self.tableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:];
```